# Roslyn – custom build error extension

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, roslyn

Is currently a way to extend Roslyn compilation and add some custom rule set that will break a build and show in ErrorList of VisualStudio?

I search StackOverflow but there is no answer that works - maybe recently something came up in this topic or maybe there is other way to do this without roslyn?

Comment: Can you describe the custom rule? It's probably possible to create a Roslyn Analyzer that issues errors (`DiagnosticSeverity.Error`) when your rule is broken.
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix

Comment: I have to force methods to be virtual due the interceptor to work - I was thinking about analyzers but main question is about breaking a build and show in error list. Can I do that?

Comment: That's exactly what analyzers do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Roslyn – custom build error extension

Just like Slaks and JoshVarty said, this is an analyzer feature. To create your custom Roslyn analyzer rule, you can check this MS tutorial:

[C# and Visual Basic - Use Roslyn to Write a Live Code Analyzer for Your API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx).

In this document, you can find following description:

> In the line declaring the Rule field, you can also update the severity
>   of the diagnostics you’ll be producing to be errors rather than
>   warnings. If the regex string doesn’t parse, the Match method will
>   definitely throw an exception at run time, and you should block the
>   build as you would for a C# compiler error. Change the rule’s severity
>   to DiagnosticSeverity.Error:
>
> ```
> internal static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule =   new
> DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat,    Category,
> DiagnosticSeverity.Error, isEnabledByDefault: true, description:
> Description);
> ```

This will cause the build to break.

And

> In order to make the build fail for the rules, you need to add the
>   analyzer as a nuget package to the project. This will ensure that
>   failures will cause the build to fail as expected.

Certification:[Roslyn Analyzer Rule does not fail the build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657589/roslyn-analyzer-rule-does-not-fail-the-build).

Hope this helps.